# Supporting White Box's M3 Controller in ROS? Supported in Player as WBR914

Tags: ros, microcontroller, player

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I recently got my first robot.. it is a WBR914 which is officially supported by player/stage.  Since ROS integrates with that system I was hoping that I could use the full ROS operating system.  Now I am learning as I go along and read more that stage is being implemented via a wrapper with ROS, and player isn't being used.

I have been following through all of the ROS tutorials doing my "Due Diligence" to learn the platform, but now I am seeing that it may be for nothing.  I was planning on using a Kinect and also a turret or robot arm from Trossen robotics to expand my robot in the future.

Is there anything which will allow me to use player with ROS, or would it be difficult to adapt the source in Player to allow my WBR914 to work natively with ROS.

It looks like this is going to be quite a project to get working, and was wondering if anyone in the community would be willing to give a hand, or take a look at the code in player and see how hard it would be to adapt.  There is a number of these WBR robots floating around on the open market right now since Heathkit went out of business.  There is the potential of about 40 of the White Box Robotics barebones hitting ebay in the near future..

I am willing to provide full remote access to my bot and work with anyone who is willing to assist in getting it working.

http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=white+Box+robotics+914

Best Regards,

Richard Graver

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40786/supporting-white-box%27s-m3-controller-in-ros?-supported-in-player-as-wbr914./) by [RchGrav](https://answers.ros.org/users/2991/rchgrav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RchGrav](https://answers.ros.org/users/2991/rchgrav/) on 2012-08-11**:
Hi Joq.  I spent an evening trying to utilize the same method as the Erratic Robot, which was invoking / wrapping the WBR914 Player driver of Player/Stage.  Thanks for the heads up on Coroware, looks like a good lead, I'll check it out.

**Comment by [RchGrav](https://answers.ros.org/users/2991/rchgrav/) on 2012-08-11**:
It seems that Coroware's website is down, maybe the company is out of business?  Anyway, the best info can probably be found here... https://www.google.com/search?q=ROS+Player+Wrapper

**Comment by [RchGrav](https://answers.ros.org/users/2991/rchgrav/) on 2012-08-11**:
Just wanted to share a video from ROSCon 2012 - Writing Hardware Drivers - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pagC2WXT1x0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably port the controller to ROS fairly easily, or even run Player in a ROS node, if desired.

See: [this related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/11213/explorer-robot-rosplayer-interface/).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0